# Integrating a function when solving a differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The example shows trying to find the general solution of $u''(x) = f(x)$ 
,where  $0<x<1$

They split it into a homogeneous and particular solution

i get how they've found the homogeneous solution .But i'm not sure how they're getting the particular integral $v(x)$ They're using a technique called variation of constants which i haven't seen before so im assuming it's just a standard technique:

Particular integral:

$v(x) = c(x) + d(x)x $

$v'(x) = c'(x) + d'(x)x + d(x)$

Impose the condition $c'(x) + d'(x)x = 0$

This leads to $v'(x) = d(x)$ and $v''(x) = d'(x) = f(x)$

I then don't understand how they integrate $d'(x) = f(x)$ 
to get $d(x) = $$ \int_{0}^{x} f(y) dy$$ $ ?

And then subbing this into $c'(x) + d'(x)x = 0$ they get that $c'(x) = -xf(x)$

Then they get (not sure how?) : $c(x) = $$ \int_{x}^{1} f(y) dy$$ $

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I don't understand, surely the simpler method would be to use the substitution $v(x)=u'(x) \implies v = \int f(x) dx$

Comment: yeah same. I think it's because they want so derive a green's function